# How to post a query result stored in array

Tags: php, arrays, post

I am using an array $data to store value returned after fetch.
This is code:

```php
<select class="span3" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" name="delete">
  <option> None</option>
    <?php 
      $data = array();
      $sel = mysql_query("select * from activity_master ORDER BY ACTNAME"); 
      while ( $res = mysql_fetch_assoc( $sel ) ) {
        $data[] = $res;
      }
      foreach( $data as $res ) { ?>
      <option value="<?php $res['ACTNAME'];?>"><?php echo $res['ACTNAME'];?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

All i need this to post the value on another page.

currently i am doing this:

```
$act = $_POST['delete']
```

on another page but the value of $act is NULL.

Plz. tell me the right code for proceed further

Comment: Do you have <form> HTML that goes with this?

Comment: try to do: var_dump($_POST) to check what is in the POST data.

Comment: can you show us a full code of form, or try to use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST`

Comment: @JAL: yes i have form with this code

Comment: @Adam: Where i have to put this var_dump($_POST) code in my page

Comment: Should it be `value="<?php echo $res['ACTNAME'];?>"`, not `value="<?php $res['ACTNAME'];?>"`?

Comment: @chiragNandwani You can put var_dump someware in php code. Could be after $act = $_POST['delete'];

Comment: @Passerby: wooah... it works .. i just forget to put echo.. thanks

Comment: @Adam: Thanks for help... i put var_dump earlier it does not show any ressult after puting echo in my code .. the value is there after var_dump.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="span3" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" name="delete">
  <option value=''> None</option>
<?php  while ( $res = mysql_fetch_assoc( $sel ) ) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $res['ACTNAME'];?>"><?php echo $res['ACTNAME'];?></option>
<?php  } ?>
</select>
```

OT: Try and avoid using mysql..() functions. try and convert your code to PDO.